# PHP7 fpm + Symfony 2.8 - 3.1, using memcached but failed to write session data to file

Tags: session, symfony, php-7

Migrating symfony apps to php 7 with no success.

## Error messages:

Symfony 2.8:

> Warning: session_write_close(): Failed to write session data (user). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/var/lib/php/sessions)

Symfony 3.1:

> Warning: session_regenerate_id(): Session object destruction failed. ID: user (path: /var/lib/php/sessions)

## Problem

Now from the message I would guess php is trying to write sessions to files.

- I use memcached handler for sessions, it is running and works with php 5.6.
- If I use `native_file` handler - everything works.

I do not know how to make any sense from this. All answers I found to similar problems include switching from native_file to memcached (already using it), changing user and/or permissions for session dir (does not matter?), updating session handler to return true from some methods (updated and checked).

## How do I debug this?

Comment: What returns `dump(ini_get('session.save_handler'));` command ?

Comment: Well, some magic happened... Dumped save_handler, it displayed `user`, changed to native_file and to memcached again - now it works! Not sure what happened, but other app on same server also started to work, nothing was changed, updated or anything. Will do more testing.

Comment: So I did not get to the bottom of this because in the end we just switched to redis. It works fine for php 5.6 and 7.1 and symfony 2.8-3.2.

Answer (score 1):

Use
`$ sudo service memcached start`

Comment: Well memcached is definitely running, no need for that. As I said, It worked with PHP 5.6.

Comment: That was the root of the problem on my docker container.. not sure what caused this issue to start happening all of a sudden, but installing memcached and starting the service fixed the problem, thank you!

Answer (score -2):

Set

```
php.auto_start=1
```

in php.ini